# Google Analytics only counts first click

Tags: javascript, button, google-analytics, analytics, tracking

I'm trying to get GA to count every hit on a button. It's not working: only the first click is being counted. And I have to wait a very long time for another click from the same pc count again.
Im using the universal code.
Thx in advance

Comment: Can you let us have a look at your code and include an actual question ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. Actually, It was just an user-end mistake.